# Buildbot 0.8.1 inactive for 2 minutes before building

Tags: buildbot

My apologies if this has been answered before - I can't seem to find any previous q&a on this.

I run buildbot 0.8.1 and use PBChangeSource() to receive changes from svn. Problem is a build will only start exactly 2 minutes after a commit. I am pretty sure there is a config somewhere that I can use to make the pause go away, but I can't find anything in the documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

That sounds like the treeStableTimer (see http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/0.8.1/full.html#Scheduler-Scheduler).

You should be able to set this to 0 (though I think it is useful to have some delay).